# How to make the hamurger menu disappear after clicking on an item in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link to the website: http://web.ntf.uni-lj.si/~mojcaovnic/.
I would like the menu to disappear when I click on a certain topic/page. I googled it and found some answers but I'm not sure what would work on my website.

Thanks

Comment: Put your code along with a valid jsFiddle working link for the issue rather than the website link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.main-navigation > ul > li').click(function(){
          $('.main-navigation').hide();
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: So sorry about my code put hide(); in place of close();

Comment: Revised : 
$(document)ready(function(){
     $('.main-navigation > ul > li').click(function(){
          $('.main-navigation').hide();
     });
});

Comment: @Vinayak you should edit your question instead of posting the revision as a comment. In addition, it's `$(document).ready()` (note the period before `ready`)

Comment: You should also test your script before posting it.

Comment: @gael I had checked his code, that's why posted my code.

Comment: So, `$(document)ready` does not generate an error?

Comment: OK, That you can point out. Anyways writing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Click` event on  'li', When `li` is clicked close sidebar.

Hope this will work.